# Smallest chain length in a Range Collatz Conjecture

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to see if I can find an algorithm such that given a range [m,n], I want to output the number such that on application of either of these steps, I can reduce the number to 1 in the minimal steps.

1. If odd, multiply by 3 and add 1.
2. If even, divide by 2.

m,n are small enough to ensure the collatz conjecture holds as the problem is directly related to it.

Now I realised that if any power of 2 lies between m and n, inclusive, that is directly the answer and that can be checked easily.

However, I couldn't find anything on the net if there was an optimal way to see if a range doesn't include a power of 2, what can be done. The brute force is way too long for this as the number of steps per number really varies and I feel this would take very long. I was wondering if there was some optimisation to this.

Comment: You can perhaps try going in the reverse direction, in a BFS fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Starting from 1 and then trying to find what is the first number I can find in that range?

Comment: The Collatz graph has edges $x\to y$ if the next number after $x$ is $y$. I'm suggesting running BFS on the reversed graph, until you get to $[m,n]$. That's probably a bit too naive, though.

Comment: I would also have to create the graph in this case, also it is fairly naive then as well. Wouldn't it be possible to say eliminate some options definitely? Like I was thinking, all numbers such as those that are 1 less than powers of 2 and are prime, say 31, these can automatically be skipped, saving a lot of time as well.

Comment: You don't have to create the graph. Given $y$, it is easy to find its possible predecessors. The number $2y$ is always a predecessor. If $y>1$ and $y \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then $(y-1)/3$ is another predecessor. That's it.

Comment: So essentially, I start from 1, start generating the numbers, say using a queue. Start by 1 in the queue. Add 2 to the queue then 4, then 8 and 16, then check for the other condition (y-1)/3 and then do this till the number inserted in the queue lies in the range [m,n]. I think this is a significant improvement as compared to the first approach of brute forcing over the range.

Asymptotically for the brute force: O((n-m)*f(x)) where f(x) is the time taken for the number to reach 1. I'm not sure how f(x) varies though, also it seems tough to see the time taken by the queue approach.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. You can use it in conjunction with the forward approach, which is better when the interval is small.

Comment: I'm finding it very tough to asymptotically analyse and compare how much of an optimization this is though. any help with that?

Comment: Our lack of understanding of Collatz sequences makes these algorithms hard to analyze analytically.